# How to play mp3+g on mediaplayer android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I know we can play mp3 file in MediaPlayer. 
But can we play mp3+g on android??

I saw in the documentation on android, but i didn't see it.
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Is there any work around or library to do this?
Thanks

Comment: you can allways play almost any kind of format on VLC , and Mp3+g its incuded like a charm :D i had already try it on my android galaxy SII and im able to read and hear the MP3 and cdg files, its all about sending it to a video and audio output, now its all about storage, most memory cards are around 32 - 64 gb capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't "think" that Android is going to support mp3+g playback anytime soon. That being said an mp3+g "file" should either be one zipped file(with two files inside) or two separate files named the same with exception of the file extension. So other then playing the MP3 there is really nothing else that MediaPLayer can do, and changing MediaPlayer int the android framework to get this to work would not be portable from device to device.

**Workaround 1**

Use FFMPEG to transcode and mux these files to a different format that is supported such as mp4. [Here](http://forum.subsonic.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7557&highlight=karaoke) is an example of someone using ffmpeg to mux mp3+g into FLV.

**Workaround 2**

Another option would be to use Android For VLC which is in pre-alpha found [here](http://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile). Now I'm not sure that VLC for android will support mp3+g, but libvlc does support decoding of the two files so I'm guessing it would work, or you could alter the code a bit to get it to work. I have checked out the VLC for Android code recently and I have to say its a cpu hog but since mp3 and cdg are generally smaller less cpu intensive files I think that android devices could handle the work load using VLC.

**Workaround 3**

Now as far as more complex options you could utilize the Android NDK and create a decoder yourself (This would take you a lot of time).

Hope some of this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution..

http://code.google.com/p/cdg-toolkit/
It was written in java so we should porting it first to Android if you want to use it.

Comment: Cool find. Let me know how that works out for you. I checked out the code. It looks like there is a lot of java.awt. I guess you could try to move some of that to Android sdk UI, but if not [this](http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/) may help you in your porting efforts. Goodluck!