# Implementing karaoke tracks in web development

Tags: html, audio, video

I'm hoping this is a good place to post this specific question. I'm putting together a side project which is going to be a web site that users can go to and sing karaoke tracks. I have 20,000+ karaoke tracks which is essentially mp3+g files (2 files in one zipped folder). When I run the zipped file(s) in a karaoke program such as siglos, it reads both the files and syncs the .mp3(audio) and .g(video) to play the track with lyrics scrolling. Anyways, looking at all the formats supported, I can't find any way in w3cschools to implement this in a website. Anyone have any experience with this or have any suggestions? Maybe web API or a program I could write that accomplishes this? Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: sorry, I barely started. As of now I'm still working on the design of the web site. I just have a poorly design html page with no functionality. I'm just trying to figure out a starting point for implementing mp3+g files into the website before I get going heavily on this. Currently midsemester in college and just planning out for knocking this out over the summer.

Comment: One idea might be to combine the two files into an mp4 (or other supported video file), using [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) or something similar. But that will definitely be a bit of a process. For reference, see [How to play mp3+g on mediaplayer android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752125/how-to-play-mp3g-on-mediaplayer-android).

Comment: ooo ok that's a good ideas. Thanks for the link and the idea.